# How can I use threading in MonoDroid such that it will be cross platform compatible with MonoTocuh

Tags: multithreading, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Specifically when doing MonoDroid uses of threads all the documentation I can find recommends calling RunOnUiThread() to call the callback.  There is a similar function that can be used on MonoTouch however both of them require a GUI (Activity or whatever its counter part is on IOS).  What I would like is to be able to start a thread, pass in a callback and call that callback on the thread that started the thread.  For example

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
{
    //Do Stuff


    execute_callback_magically_on_main_thread(() => callback(response));
});
```

Any ideas?   To be clear I would prefer this to not need a handle to the Activity etc.

Comment: Why not just raise an event and let the view itself determine how to get it marshaled to the UI thread in it's own platform-specific mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works and does not appear to be dependent on either platform.

```
Task<string> t = new Task<string>(() =>
{
    //Do Stuff
    return "my results";
});
t.ContinueWith(task =>{
    if(callback != null)
         callback(task.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
t.Start();
```

The important part is the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() which tells the "ContinueWith" to execute on the original thread.

Comment: I thought the point was that you needed something executed on the UI thread specifically not to just be able to do background tasks?

Comment: What I needed was something that would be able to execute on the UI thread, this does that, provided the UI thread starts it.  The ContinueWith portion executes on the parent thread, because of the "FromCurrentSyncronizationContext()" call.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like this? (assuming they have the same signature) I haven't messed with `RunOnUiThread`, so I don't know it's signature.

```
    public delegate void InvokeOnUIMethod(Action action);

    public void CallingMethod()
    {
        //iOS
        MyMethod(InvokeOnMainThread, () => { /* Your callback functionality  */ });

        //Android
        MyMethod(RunOnUiThread, () => { /* Your callback functionality  */ });
    }

    public void MyMethod(InvokeOnUIMethod execute_callback_magically_on_main_thread, Action callback)
    {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
            //Do Stuff

            execute_callback_magically_on_main_thread(() => callback(response));
        });
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was my first thought as well.  But in order for this to work on android you have to have a reference to the Activity and in IOS you have to a reference to the NSObject.  I am making these calls from library since I am trying to segment my logic from my ui so having those references is not easy.  I could pass them but they dont really share a common ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Alpha builds (Hopefully soon to be available as stable) you can use the new Async await idiom.

here is an overview on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

and here is a great video series on Channel9:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-1-Async-void-is-for-top-level-event-handlers-only